# Android resource compilation failed error:

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, aapt, aapt2

After migrating my project to androidx and fixing all imports and layout files, i get the following compilation error

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception:

    Android resource compilation failed error: .
```

I have tried to run code inspection and fixed any lint related issues but still getting the same error.
Here is the link to build scan 
https://scans.gradle.com/s/y7b5v37gl2yvs

Comment: The rest of the stack trace shows which resources are missing. Post the entire the stack trace and not part of it.

Comment: @SrikarReddy I have updated the question with link to gradle build scan

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because of some referenced String Resources or another type of resources is not imported in the project. Please check if you have used two different string files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should need to upgrade this one also

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}
```